# not able to get the time value and submited when date and time buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to make a booking without submit button i have many buttons to select a time and a date picker

i want data to be submited when date and time buttons are clicked

i am not able to get the time value also

```
var doctorid = props
const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());
  const changeDate = (e) => {
    setDateState(e);
  };
 function booking() {
 
    const data = {
      date: dateState,
      time: "12:pm",/// time button value must come here 
      doctor: doctorid,
    };
```

this   is the jsx

```
<Calendar value={dateState} onChange={changeDate} />
             

 <TabPanel>
                  <button style={styles.button}>9:00am</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>9:30am</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>10:00am</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>10:30am</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>11:00am</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>11:30am</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>12:00pm</button>
  </TabPanel>
<TabPanel>
                  <button style={styles.button}>6:30pm</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>7:00pm</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>7:30pm</button>
                  <button style={styles.button}>8:00pm</button>
                </TabPanel>
```

i am not able to get the time value also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setDateState(e) should be setDateState(e.target.value);